# Is it possible to add a link an html link to jquery draggable/droppable text?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to add a link to the end of some text that is being dropped. At Spiritfyre's and tehlulz's suggestion below I changed `$( "<li class='padding0'></li>" ).text( ...` to `$( "<li class='padding0'></li>" ).html( ...` in the code below.

jQuery drop:

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "<li class='padding0'></li>" ).html( ui.draggable.text() + " <a href='/items/1' data-method='delete' rel='nofollow'><img alt='Delete' src='/images/delete.png?1335803006' /></a>" ).appendTo( this );
}
```

The link is still rendered as text. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: try `$( "<li class='padding0'></li>" ).html(` over `$( "<li class='padding0'></li>" ).text(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .html() instead of .text()

.html() sets the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements while .text() sets the text contents of each element.

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "<li class='padding0'></li>" ).html( ui.draggable.text() + " <a href='/items/1' data-method='delete' rel='nofollow'><img alt='Delete' src='/images/delete.png?1335803006' /></a>" ).appendTo( this );
}
```